# How to correctly specify when testing a component in an Angular that which component has input data in generic type

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I want to test a component,  which can accept array with a different types of data, for existence, but Typescript show me an error:

```
Error:(7, 18) TS2314: Generic type 'AppTableComponent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

My component file:

```
export class AppTableComponent<T> {
  @Input() data: T[];

  constructor() {}
}
```

Test file

```
describe('AppTableComponent', () => {
  let component: AppTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppTableComponent,
        MockComponent( PreloaderComponent ),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a type argument, just as the error indicates.

As the actual type argument isn't meaningful in the test case you specified above, I would recommend using `unknown` for maximum safety.

```
let component: AppTableComponent<unknown>;
```

If a test involves assigning to the input, you would need to specify the type argument explicitly when calling `TestBed.createComponent` like so

```
 TestBed.createComponent<AppTableComponent<string>>(AppTableComponent);
```